# How do I delete a list of files using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to writing batch files and I need to write one in order to delete a list of files please. I need the batch script to first locate the files (they are all based in different folders in the same drive) and then subsequently delete all of them. Is there a way that I can write a batch script to locate the files in a list and then delete them all automatically?

Apologies for how basic this question is - I am completely unsure how to go about this task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('dir /s /b /a-d "c:\%%i"') do echo del "%%j"
)
```

remove the `echo`, if the output satisfies you.

get every filename in your list (%%i)

. get every full path (%%j) for this filename (search through the disk) and delete it.

NOTE: this is not fast - searching the whole disk for every single filename needs some time.

If there are many filenames in your list, it may be better to build a complete direcotry-tree only once and write it to a file (`dir /s /c /a-d >diskcontent.txt`), working with that file instead of searching the disk for every file.

dir-parameters: `/s` search in all subdirectories, `/b` use a format that gives you the complete path, `/a-d` exclude directorynames; `c:\` start in the root of drive `C:`

**EDIT**

if your `list.txt` contains spaces (either in the filename or in a given path), you have several options:

```
pushd "C:\path to\my file"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) do (
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "C:\path to\my file\list.txt"' ) do (
```

or

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("C:\path to\my file\list.txt") do (
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your reply! I appreciate you breaking down what the dir-parameters mean so that I can learn what I'm doing.

When I put in the full path of list.txt and try to run it, it just says 'File Not Found' - any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I think I'm putting the file path in correctly.

Comment: Does the full path contain spaces?